# Security rules interpretation for rest and web different?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am trying to read `<<firebaseurl>>/test` by appending `.json` to it but I keep getting permission denied no matter what I do.

My security rules:

```
{
"rules": {
    "test" : {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "users" : {
      "$userid": {
        ".read": "$userid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$userid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
}
}
```

accessing the data using js works as intended:

```
ref.child("test").once( 'value', function(snap){
                    console.log(snap.val());
                });
```

but when I try to get the data using json

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'https://instance.firebaseio.com/test.json',
 dataType: 'json' ,
 type: 'GET',
 error: function() {
   //handle it
 },
 success: function(data) {     
   //do something
 }
});
```

throws a permission denied error. Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ajax request is returning permission denied because you have a security rule that requires authentication, but you tried to fetch the data via HTTP without any authentication. You need to pass an authentication token in your request, which you can create using your Firebase Secret via the customer token generator for Simple Login (check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/XDXu5/embedded/result/). You can find your Secret by navigating to the "Secrets" tab in your Firebase Dashboard. So your request will look something like:

```
url: 'https://instance.firebaseio.com/test.json?auth=TOKEN'
```